# Laravel and vue - VerifyCsrfToken except don't working

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, axios

I send some POST request by my 'presenze' application with Vue axios to another laravel server 'AUTHSERVER'.
If I set the middleware VerifyCsrfToken.php so:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{    
    protected $except = [
        '*'        
    ];
}
```

it works very good, but if I make this:

```
 protected $except = [
        'http://presenze',
        'http://presenze/*',
    ];
```

I receive this error:

```
XHRPOSThttp://authserver/login/mysql_verify
[HTTP/1.1 419 unknown status 9ms]   
....
```

what is the just way to write the except array in the middleware? App requesting is 'http://presenze' !
Can anyone help me please?
thanks.
bye.

Comment: if you want to not verify the csrf token EVER, just remove the middleware   `:)` ... though you probably actually want this protection ... on what server did you adjust this middleware? because the auth server isn't `http://presenze`

Comment: `$except` expects routes(paths), not entire URLs. just add only the path that you need to exclude from CSRF validation. i.e: protected $except = ['/users']. If you have multiple domain, create a separate route file for that and don't add CSRF middleware to that

Comment: @RavishaHesh I thought the same thing but apparently you can pass a full URL https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris .... though this might be a newer things because I was pretty sure in the past it was just "path patterns"

Comment: @lagbox hmmm, Just saw that. Also why the response URL  `http://authserver/login/mysql_verify` doesn't have `http://presenze` in it? `authserver` is another domain?

Comment: @RavishaHesh it almost looks like they are using except as though it is for checking a referrer or something

Comment: @lagbox _if you want to not verify the csrf token EVER, just remove the middleware_ : I want to verify all except presenze/* request :)

Comment: @RavishaHesh _expects routes(paths), not entire URLs_ :  I try with all : 'presenze/*', /presenze', '/presenze', '/presenze/*', 'http://....' but it does'nt work!

Comment: @ottaviane `http://authserver/login/mysql_verify` doesn't have a `presenze` segment

Answer (score 0):

I made it in VerifyCsrfToken.php Middleware:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{    
    protected $except = [
        'api/*',
    ];
}
```

and all routes I trasformed from /presenze/*  in /api/*
Now it works fine.
I think it need to be called with the standard /api/ prefix ... I think.
Do you know another explanation? If anyone knows, your intervention is welcome.